# Find the minimum distance that equal maximum inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $x_0 \in$ $H$ (Hilbert Space) and $M$ is a closed linear subspace of $H$, prove that

$$\min \{\|x - x_0\|: x \in M\} = \max \{\langle x_0, y\rangle : y \in M^\perp, \|y\| = 1\}.$$

I suppose $P$ and $Q$ are the orthogonal projections so that $x_0=Px_0+Qx_0$, clearly left side  is $Px_0$ now how to show right side (of the identity asked in question) is also $Px_0$.

I appreciate your help..

Comment: What do you mean by "...LHS is $Px_0$ now how to show RHS is also $Px_0$"? I'm not being obtuse, I really don't understand. Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this holds. If $H=\mathbb R^2$ and $x$ is $(1,0)$, $M$ is the x-axis then the minimal distance between $x$ and the x-axis is zero but the minimal distance between points on the y-axis with $\|y\|=1$ is strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: Is there a condition missing or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: $Px_0$ is orthogonal projection of $x_0$ onto $M$ which is what left side means but how does right side is $Px_0$

Comment: But left side of what?

Comment: I have copied the question from book, i guess nothing is missing, it does not say any specific Hilbert space. I don't know if we are allowed to take $\Bbb R^2 $

Comment: left side and right side of identity asked in problem

Comment: r u still confused?

Comment: Yes, I'm still trying to understand.

Comment: I may be wrong, is left side of question equals $Px_0$? Or it equals $Qx_0$? Wher $P$ and $Q$ are the orthogonal projections onto $M$ and $M^\perp$

Comment: Hint: If $y\in M$ minimises $\lVert x_0-x\rVert$, then $(x_0-y)\perp M$.

Comment: @Daniel, I have seen this written somewhere but I'm not able to visualize it clearly so i am confused. Could you plz elaborate little bit..

Comment: Ah, rats, should have named it $z$, not $y$. Anyway, with $z\in M$ and $x_0 - z \in M^\perp$, do you see a connection to the desired maximum?

Comment: @Justin : You don't need to keep alternating in and out of MathJax code.  I've edited it so that the displayed line starting with "min" is entirely in MathJax.

Comment: @Justin : The left side is $\|x_0 - Px_0\|$, not just $x_0$.  Clearly both sides are scalars, not points in Hilbert space.

Comment: Lots of comments, but I'm the only person who's up-voted the question so far.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer and missed a couple of details, and now I hope I've fixed that.  If some details are still imperfect, I think the idea is nonetheless right, but tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each point $x_0\in H$ there exists exactly one pair of members of $H$ which let us call $Px_0$ and $Qx_0$ such that $Px_0\in M$ and $Qx_0\in M^\perp$.  For each $x\in M$, consider
$$
x_0-x = (x_0-Px_0)+(Px_0-x).
$$
Show that the inner product of these two summands is $0$.  Then show that
$$
\|x_0-x\|^2 = \|x_0-Px_0\|^2+\|Px_0-x\|^2.
$$
As $x$ moves around within $M$, the second term on the right side above changes and the first does not, and the second term is $0$ iff $x=Px_0$.  Therefore the smallest that $\|x_0-x\|^2$ can be made the value of the first term on the right, and that is the square of the norm of $x_0-Px_0 = Qx_0\in M^\perp$.

It will now be enough to show that for every $y\in M^\perp$ with $\|y\|=1$, we have
$$
\langle y, x_0\rangle \le \left\langle \frac{Qx_0}{\|Qx_0\|},x_0\right\rangle
$$
with equality only when $y=Qx_0/\|Qx_0\|$.  We have
$$
\langle y,x_0\rangle = \langle y, Px_0+Qx_0\rangle = \langle y, Px_0\rangle+\langle y,Qx_0\rangle = 0 + \langle y,Qx_0\rangle.$$
So we want to show that
$$
\langle y,Qx_0\rangle \le \left\langle x_0, \frac{Qx_0}{\|Qx_0\|}\right\rangle
$$
with equality only when $y=Qx_0/\|Qx_0\|$.

Show that this statement is the same as saying that for $y\in M^\perp$ with $\|y\|=1$,
$$
\langle y, Qx_0\rangle \le \left\langle Qx_0,\frac{Qx_0}{\|Qx_0\|} \right\rangle
$$
with equality only when $y=Qx_0/\|Qx_0\|$.

All the vectors you see in the displayed line above are in the Hilbert space $M^\perp$.  So the problem now is to show that if $y_0$ is in some Hilbert space $y$ is some member of that Hilbert space with $\|y\|=1$, then
$$
\langle y,y_0\rangle \le \left\langle y_0,\frac{y_0}{\|y_0\|}\right\rangle
$$
with equality only when $y=y_0/\|y_0\|$.

Can you do the rest?

Comment: PS: The place where we used the fact that $M$ is closed was where the orthogonal projection onto $M$ was taken to exist. For example, the set of all trigonometric polynomials, $\left\{\sum_{n=-N}^N c_n e^{in\theta} : N\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\} \right\}$ is a non-closed subspace of $L^2(0,2\pi)$, and in general a member of that Hilbert space has no orthogonal projection onto that subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Because $M$ is closed, then $H=M\oplus M^{\perp}$. So there is a unique $m \in M$ such that $(x_{0}-m)\perp M$. Then, for any other $m\in m'$, $(x_{0}-m)\perp (m-m')$ and
$$
              \|x_{0}-m'\|^{2}=\|(x_{0}-m)+(m-m')\|^{2}=\|x_{0}-m\|^{2}+\|m-m'\|^{2} \ge \|x_{0}-m\|^{2}.
$$
Therefore, $\min_{x \in M}\|x_{0}-x\|=\|x_{0}-m\|$. Assume that $x_{0}\ne M$ so that $x_{0}-m$ may be normalized to a unit vector $\hat{y}=\|x_{0}-m\|^{-1}(x_{0}-m)$. Because $\hat{y}$ is orthogonal to $M$,
$$
        (x_{0},\hat{y})=(x_{0}-m,\hat{y})=\|x_{0}-m\|^{-1}(x_{0}-m,x_{0}-m)=\|x_{0}-m\|.
$$
On the other hand, if $\hat{y}'$ is a unit vector with $\hat{y}'\perp M$, then
$$
      |(x_{0},\hat{y}')|=|(x_{0}-m,\hat{y}')| \le \|x_{0}-m\|\|\hat{y}'\|=\|x_{0}-m\|,
$$
and $|(x_{0},\hat{y}')|=\|x_{0}-m\|$ iff $(x_{0}-m)$ and $\hat{y}'$ are linearly dependent (which gives $\hat{y}'=\alpha\hat{y}$ for some unimodular scalar $\alpha$.)